# Reconnect socat connection after network failure

Tags: socat

I am using a socat command to create a tty interface on my embedded linux device like:

```
socat pty,link=/dev/ttyS9 TCP:10.0.10.1:9999
```

The connection is a long distance connecstion over a dsl-line. This line is disconnected every night and my tty interface is down. Is it possible to create the tty interace with a mechanism to reconnect until the server side is online again?

Next question: is it possible to call the socat command from a java programm?

Thanks a lot!
Karl-Heinz

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 8):

As of version V 1.4.0.0 socat features the options "retry", "forever", and "interval".

So, this should give you the desired behavior:

```
socat pty,link=/dev/ttyS9 tcp:10.0.10.1:9999,forever,interval=10,fork
```

Comment: This only works on first connection. If the connection is closed it will not reconnect.

Comment: @lethalman Do you mind to explain your setup? Do you use `socat` on both ends? Did you set the `forever` option on both ends?

Comment: `socat - tcp:foo,forever` will try to reconnect forever if the first connection is not successful. But after the connection is established, socat will just quit if the endpoint disconnects.

Answer (score 2):

Socat is designed to exit when one connection closes.

Workaround: put a infinite loop around your socat start

```
  while true
    do 
      socat addr1 addr2
      sleep 1
    done
```

Comment: I would also recommend using the `keepalive` option for the unstable address. Without this option `socat` might not notice when the connection is lost.