# socat as client must reconnect to server and continue using same pty file

Tags: linux, socat

I am using socat to connect to a server and transfer the incoming data to a file that can be read by another process. This is unidrectional data (from the server to the receiving process).

Because socat exits when my server goes down or disconnects, I am using a loop so that socat can reconnect. My code is below.

The problem is when socat reconnects, it also opens a new file to write the data into, going from dev/pts/0 to dev/pts/1, possibly because my receiving process still has the file open for reading.

The reading process does not know of the file change and therefore cannot read data that is going into the new file.

Is there a way for socat continue to write into the same file after a reconnect?

Or some other method that can handle the sever reconnect in a better way?

Thanks

I have already consulted the similar topic here:

[Reconnect socat connection after network failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341254/reconnect-socat-connection-after-network-failure)

but it's a slightly different problem.

I have also tried using a fork method but I end up with multiple child processes connecting to the server when I just want the one connection. (I suspect the fork method is meant for socat as a server, not as a client).

My code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/dev/ttyv0"
while :
do
    if [ -f "$file" ];then
        cho "$file found,go to connect"
    else
        socat -d -d -U  pty,link=/dev/ttyv0,raw,crnl tcp:192.168.0.161:9800
    fi
done
```

Thanks again

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1295749/632343) might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have tried the ignoreeof option but that does not stop socat from exiting. (because it's not a real EOF character being read, but mereIy the fact that the file is now empty).  I have also tried keepalive, even though that has nothing to do with keeping socat alive, it refers to TCP keepalive messages being sent to the server, which is already down in this case anyway.

Comment: I am wondering if the key is to be able to share the file.

Comment: Maybe I need to use a mode other than pty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what we came up with (tested and working):

```
#!/bin/bash

socat pty,link=/dev/ttyv0,raw,crnl pty,link=/dev/ttyv1,raw,crnl

while true 
do
        socat  -U open:/dev/ttyv1,raw,nonblock tcp:192.168.0.161:9800,forever
done
```

We end up running socat twice, with two files.

The second socat reads from the server to file 1.

The first socat reads from file 1 into file 0.

The reader process reads the data from file 0.

The two files are always there and the reader process can always read from the same file, regardless of any server restarts.

Compliments to GC for this solution.